# putting a podfile in the project. confusion

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash

So I have a issue with my app not building in the sim anymore. This happened right after I moved the workspace to the actual projects folder. I don't know how the workspace was outside the project folder, but I moved it so I could install some firebase pods. So, my question is... Is there anyway to fix this issue without moving it back outside the project folder? Or would it just make the problem bigger?

---

Okay so I created a new project all together and I'm trying to put a pod in the folder, but I don't know what I am doing to cause this.... should I put my podfile outside the folder that the terminal shows? Like should I go up one to access the actual xcode project file?

[Terminal View of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwZuV.png)

[Finder View of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioyGq.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "the workspace was outside the project folder"?

Comment: my question is updated now :)

Comment: You need to go back a level in terminal and then do pod init. It should happen in the project root directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I had to go back a folder where the Xcode project file is. The confusion was the two 'EXTBP' folders.